# Can the Corporation know which HQ cards were accessed?

Tags: android-netrunner

When the Runner accesses cards from the Corporation's HQ, does the Corporation get to know which cards were accessed, or are they returned to the HQ before the Corporation sees them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Netrunner FAQ](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/android-netrunner/support/FAQ/Android-Netrunner%20FAQ.pdf):

> **Does the Corp know which cards the Runner accesses from HQ?**
>
> Yes. The Corp should know what cards are accessed and in what order.